# Remove duplicates from dataframe but keep the values of other dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Is the following dataframe

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[1001, 120,np.nan], [1001,np.nan ,30], [1004, 160,np.nan],[1005, 160,np.nan], 
                   [1006,np.nan ,8], [1010, 160,np.nan],[1010,np.nan ,4]], columns=['CustomerNr','Period1','Period2'])
```

|  | CustomerNr | Period1 | Period2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1001 | 120.0 | NaN |
| 1 | 1001 | NaN | 30.0 |
| 2 | 1004 | 160.0 | NaN |
| 3 | 1005 | 160.0 | NaN |
| 4 | 1006 | NaN | 8.0 |
| 5 | 1010 | NaN | 4.0 |
| 6 | 1010 | 160.0 | NaN |

and i need to generate this where actually duplicated CustomerNr are eliminated but the values of Period1 and Period 2 are kept.

|  | CustomerNr | Period1 | Period2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1001 | 120.0 | 30.0 |
| 1 | 1004 | 160.0 | NaN |
| 2 | 1005 | 160.0 | NaN |
| 3 | 1006 | NaN | 8.0 |
| 4 | 1010 | 160.0 | 4 |

Comment: You'll want to look into the `groupy` method of the data frame, and then the `agg` (for aggregate) method of the resulting grouped dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

```py
df.groupby('CustomerNr').agg('min')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `groupby` and take the `first` item per group, by default the NaNs are ignored in the `groupby` operations:

```
df.groupby('CustomerNr').first()
```

output:

```
             Period1   Period2
CustomerNr                    
1001        120.0000   30.0000
1004        160.0000       NaN
1005        160.0000       NaN
1006             NaN    8.0000
1010        160.0000    4.0000
```

Comment: I have another question to this. If the values of Period1 and Period2 are not numbers but text values. How can i generate this.

Comment: If you have `NaN`s this should world exactly the same. If you have empty strings, first replace them with `NaN` and proceed